# Oracle Virtual Box not displaying Ip address

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have installed oracle virtual machine on window 10. My system 
is connected to internet via a USB modem. I have already enabled DHCP on my window 10 OS and everything seems to be working except that I cannot find my IP Address when i run command **IP ADDRESS**.

Please how can I find my IP ADDRESS from the oracle VMW since am connected to internet via USB Modem

**Below is the screenshot without working IP ADDRESS based on tutorial am reading..**

[myscreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSw7D.png)

Thanks

Comment: ip a |grep -w inet

Answer (score 0):

Try this link from oracle for looking at your guest machines IP addresses

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E50245_01/E50251/html/vmadm-guestadd-ipdisplay.html

Here is a link on how to install the guest additions for oracle vm if you haven't installed it on the guest os yet.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36500_01/E36502/html/qs-guest-additions.html

Lastly, here is a link to open the guest addition display

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E27300_01/E27308/html/vmiug-manager-start-stop.html